# javascript choices for looping over select options

Tags: javascript

Recently I stole some javascript to select an option in a select element:

```
    var el=document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var opts=el.options;
    for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
        if (opt.value == 'Apple') {
          el.selectedIndex = j;
          break;
      }
    }
```

It works fine, but as I looked at it I realized it was different from what I would have written:

```
    var el=document.getElementById('mySelect');
    for (var j = 0; j < el.options.length; j++) {
        if (el.options[j].value == 'Apple') {
          el.selectedIndex = j;
          break;
      }
    }
```

In looking at the first code, what stops the loop if 'Apple' is not found?  Which one is 'better'?

Comment: The test is the return value of `opt = opts[j]` which is *opt*. When *j* reaches *opts.length* the value will be *undefined*, which is falsey so the loop stops. What are your criteria for "better"? There are many alternatives, in order to determine "better" you need to say how they should be evaluated (faster, easier to maintain, shorter, etc.).

Comment: I suppose what stops it is opt = opts[j] is falsey when opts runs out, seems a bit cutesy to me. Perhaps someone can give a justification for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either case, the second expression determines if the loop should continue or stop. In yours,

```
for (var j = 0; j < el.options.length; j++) {}
```

it's straightforward, `j` will increment and as long as `j` is less than the options length it's true, and at some point it is equal to the length and then it stops. In the other one,

```
for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {}
```

the difference is that they are declaring a variable `opt` and in the second expression set it to the (also incrementing) array index. At some point, `j` goes beyond the bounds of the array, and `opts[j]` is `undefined`. And since an equality expression in JS is the value of the right site, that expression is also `undefined`, which is falsy, and the loop stops.

As for which is better? Both work. But as you had to scratch your head and wonder about one of them, how much do you want to depend on code that's more difficult to read?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:

In your for loop `var opt` is executed once after which you have subsequent `opt = data[i]`.

This is important because:

```js
var opt, data = [1, 2];    // defined once
console.log(opt = data[0]) // 1
console.log(opt = data[1]) // 2
console.log(opt = data[2]) // undefined
```

When the [for loop condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) evaluates to [**falsy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it will halt.

So in your case it does stop when `opt = data[i]` ends up being a `falsy` value - `undefined`

> Which is at the point of `i` being `5` and `data[i]` becoming undefined and being assigned to `opt` ... which returns as a final result `undefined`.

You should also consider using this (if ES6 is an option):

```
var el=document.getElementById('mySelect');
el.selectedIndex = el.options.findIndex(x => x.value === 'Apple')
```

It is shorted and easier to read :).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question "*what stops the loop if 'Apple' is not found?*"

Comment: OK that should do it I think.